# Сохранение данных swift

Tags: ios, save, swift4

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня никак не получается сохранять данные myDate в файл .txt что только не пробовал. Я считываю показатели акселерометра и после вывожу их в командную строку, а хочу сохранять

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var motionManager = CMMotionManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in

        if let myData = data
        {

            //if myData.acceleration.x > 1
            //{
                print (myData)
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы хотите сохранять в файл, то добавьте:

```
let logFilePath = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("LogFile.txt"))!

/// Запись в файл если пусто, дозапись, если что-то уже есть
func logToFile(data: Data) {
    guard let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: logFilePath.path) else {
        try! data.write(to: logFilePath)
        return
    }
    fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
    fileHandle.write(data)
    fileHandle.closeFile()
}

/// Для распечатки сохраненных в файл логов.
func printLogFileData() {
    let result = try! String(contentsOf: logFilePath, encoding: .utf8)
    print(result)
}
```

И в вместо `print (myData)` вызывайте:

```
self.logToFile(data: "\(myData)\n".description.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
```